# Zend Framework 2 set translator for Navigation-Helper within the layout

Tags: layout, navigation, zend-framework2

Starting with the skeleton application I want to create a multilingual project. For the Navigation I'm using Zend\Navigation. Everyhting works well - not setting a translator for the navigation view helper.

The translator is registered within the module.config.php and works well for all kinds of translations (including translate view helper, also within layout). But to be able to translate labels of the navigation I need to set the translator to the navigation view helper. According to the documentation this could be done like this:

```
$this->navigation()->setTranslator($translator);
```

Or something like that. Problem is that I can't find out how to fetch the configured translator from within the layout. Is there a way to access the ServiceManager or getting the service locator?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting the translator with the navigation, since it's already configured as you said, you could use TextDomain instead. Here is what I currently do:

$this->navigation('Zend\Navigation\Navigation')->setTranslatorTextDomain('textdomainhere');

Of course if all your translations are in the same textdomain of default, then you don't need to set anything: $this->navigation('Zend\Navigation\Navigation');

As for getting the translate working in the layout all you do is:

echo $this->translate('Translate This Text', 'textdomainhere');